# extension of absolute values in function fields and product formula

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-numbers

Let $\Omega$ be the completion of an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_q\left(\left(\frac1T\right)\right)$ for the valuation $-\deg$. Let $K/\mathbb F_q(T)$ be a algebraic extension of finite dimension $n$ and unseparability degree $u$. Denote by $|.|_{\infty_i}$ ($1\le i\le g$) be the normalized absolute values of $K$ above prolonging the infinite absolute value of $\mathbb F_q(T)$. Can one assert that for all $x\in K$, one has
$$\prod_{i=1}^g|x|_{\infty_i}\le q^{nu\deg(x)}.$$
Obviously, one has the equality for $x\in \mathbb F_q(T)$. Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: What is the rôle of $\Omega$ in your question?

Comment: $\Omega$ is where the $-\deg$ valuation lives. I could have taken only an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_q(\left(\left(\frac 1T\right)\right)$ if you prefer.

Comment: I just meant that, after defining $\Omega$, it seems that you do not use it again.

Comment: I use it through $\deg$.

Comment: $\deg(x)$ is not well defined the way you suggest. $K$ may have several different embeddings into $\Omega$. You may want to define $\deg(x) = [K:\mathbb{F}_q(x)]$ but that's a different question.

Comment: Sorry my queston is not relevant. I have difficulties with embeddings.